# Как программисту искать информацию?

Tags: android, поиск-библиотек, информация

Часто сталкиваюсь с ситуацией, когда передо мной стоит конкретная задача (к примеру - тестовое задание), для выполнения которой необходимо использовать навыки и технологии, которыми я раньше никогда не пользовался. Обычно на поиск информации уходит достаточно много времени, приходится перерывать огромное количество "бесполезной" информации, перед тем, как я найду хоть что-то, что относится к решаемой мной проблеме и, в то же время, не устарело.
Лишь пару месяцев назад я научился пользоваться поиском на GitHub (узнал, что искать можно по всему сайту, а не только в конкретном аккаунте).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быстро находить необходимую информацию

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Единственный и самый рабочий вариант - через [Google](https://www.google.ru/). Используя данную поисковую систему можно найти все что угодно в том числе и решение вашей задачи. Проблема которую вы описали, а именно низкая скорость при поиске информации - это всего лишь отсутствие опыта в той или иной области. Грубо говоря вы не знаете что искать, и самый первый запрос в гугл довольно обширный и обтекаемый. Дальше после, например, 5-10 минут поисков вы находите первую тропинку. Вы ухватываетесь за полученную крошку информации, и уже ее начинаете использовать в последующих запросах. И так каждый раз, то есть грубо говоря используя первый вопрос, вероятность нахождения "идеального" ответа равна почти 0 (не 0 потому что есть и случайное событие) и с каждым новым запросом вы постепенно повышаете вероятность нахождения того самого решения которое и поможет вам.

Но я дам совет, не уверен что он правильный и полезный, но тем не менее мне кажется он вам поможет - ищите ключевые слова в источниках. Именно вы являетесь соперником гугла (в переносном смысле конечно) при поиске информации. Вот например, вы нашли статью где дан обширный ответ на ваш самый первый запрос, но в данной статье есть слова/словосочетания которые будут строить ваш следующий запрос. Учитесь находить и вычленять из всей массы "нужной" информации именно ту которая в дальнейшем будем использована дальше. Этим самым вы увеличите скорость поиска. По итогу, вам будет довольно просто находить ключевые слова и генерировать новые запросы намного быстрее и как результат - ваша производительность вырастет :) **Не отчаивайтесь, вы на верном пути, главное не сдавайтесь и верьте в свои силы. Удачи :)**

Comment: @Andrew, спасибо за совет и пожелания)

Comment: @AlexKhonko, благодарю)